# Need help with checking whether a predicate logic formula is a tautology.

Tags: logic

I have an example like this, and I don't know how to solve it (check if is tautology):
$\left(\exists_{x} \forall_{y}: q(x,y) \Rightarrow \forall_{y} \exists_{x}:q(x,y)\right)$

So the question is how to find out is this tautology? I thought  first like this:

$\left(\forall_{y}: q(a,y) \Rightarrow \forall_{y}: q(f(y),y)\right)$

Am i doing it right? What should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

If you think it may be a tautology, then it would mean that it is impossible for the antecedent to be true and the consequent false, so proof by contradiction could be a way to go. The one given below is quite informal.

Suppose for contradiction the negation of the conditional, i.e. suppose that $(\exists x)(\forall y)P(x,y)$ is true and the negated consequent, i.e. $ \neg (\forall y)(\exists x)P(x,y)$, is also true.

Now, in the antecedent let $\alpha$ be such that $(\forall y)P(\alpha,y)$, and by applying syntactic rules for quantifiers and negation see that the consequent is equivalent to $(\exists y)(\forall x)\neg P(x,y)$. Next, in the consequent let $\beta$ be such that $(\forall x)\neg P(x,\beta)$, so in particular it follows that $\neg P(\alpha,\beta)$, and $\beta$ warrants the truth of $(\exists y)\neg P(\alpha,y)$, which is equivalent to $\neg (\forall y)P(\alpha,y)$, contradicting the earlier hypothesis $(\forall y)P(\alpha,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are given that there exists an $x$ such that for all $y$, $q(x,y)$ holds. You want to show that for all $y$ there exists $x(y)$ such that $q(x(y),y)$ holds. Can you think of a good choice for $x(y)$?

Comment: So the answer is that it is tautology? I completely green in this so tell me;/

Comment: A tautology is a statement that is always valid. Is this statement always valid? If so, it is a tautology.

Comment: but how can i say about all value when i dont know it? q can be true and false the same p